# What is a common English expression for when you were very tired or out of it and said something extremely stupid?

Tags: expressions, american-english, expression-choice

I kept thinking of "spazzing out" but that doesn't quite seem to be it. An example is when you're very tired and kind of dozing off and you say something or ask a question that is incredibly stupid and makes no sense.

Comment: You can say that you're _spaced out_ or _zoned out_. _Spazzed out_ suggests that you keep dropping your spaghetti fork into someone else's lap.

Comment: _Brain fart_ means something similar.

Comment: I see the American English tag, and it seems from [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spastic) that *spaz/spastic* is not particularly offensive. It's very rarely used in British English: even the Spastics Society changed its name to Scope.

Comment: 'Not particularly offensive'? That’s not how I read the article.

Comment: 'Flaky' describes the situation bit also many similar (don't have to be tired, doesn't have to be something stupid said)

Comment: @BarrieEngland not particularly in America, which I think is Andrew's point.

Comment: @AndrewLeach It's rarely used in British English to refer to  cerebral palsy, because it is very commonly used as a general insult. The time-line given in that article is quite bogus, as it suggests the non-insulting use dropped, and the insulting use rose, after the Spastic Society changed its name, when the language was one of their reasons for the name change.

Comment: @JonHanna The article is badly sequenced, but it's fairly clear that the insulting use grew in the 1980s and the Spastics Society changed its name in 1994. [And yes, the point I was making in my comment was that it's just not acceptable any more in BrE, whatever AmE attributes to the term.]

Comment: @AndrewLeach Ah, I get you. Certainly, growing up it was one of the favourite insults among children of my age, and considered just a shade below the famous four-letter-word F- and C-words with it's use tantamount to a challenge to fisticuffs, while actually using it to refer to a spastic was not on (we were too young to appreciate Ian Dury's fantastic anthem).

Answer (score 2):

This may not be very close to what you are looking for, but ***freudian slip*** could be considered. I am suggesting the idiom because the definitions below do hint at saying something stupid.

> Freudian slip:
>
> 1] If someone makes a Freudian slip, they accidentally use the wrong word, but in doing so reveal what they are really thinking rather than what they think the other person wants to hear. ([Source](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/freudian+slip.html))
>
> 2] A slip of the tongue that allegedly reveals repressed desires and thoughts. ([Source](http://www.idiomquest.com/learn/idiom/Freudian-slip/))
>
> 3] an unintentional error regarded as revealing subconscious feelings. ([Source](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/Freudian+slip?q=Freudian%20slip))

Comment: There is also malapropism and spoonerism, but I agree Freudian slip is the best answer.

Answer (score 1):

The general English term is *sleep talk* (or *sleep talking*). The Latin medical term is *somniloquy*. Sleep talk can be intelligible or pure gibberish. It can occur in any stage of sleep, including the first stage as one is falling asleep.

A starting point for more information is the “Somniloquy” entry at *Wikipedia*.[¹](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somniloquy)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I am focusing too much on the fact that what is being said is extremely stupid, but I think it depends on how much is being said by this very tired or spaced out individual.

**Blurting out** might be a good fit if the person suddenly says a word or phrase that makes no sense or is inappropriate.

Like this morning in my organization's meeting, before I had had my coffee, we were asked to give input on our scale-up strategy. I wasn't paying attention, but I heard my name called. "I agree," I blurted out. It soon became clear that I had been asked to go answer the front door.

**Rambling** or **babbling** would be better used if the speaker were going on at length, saying lots of nonsensical or stupid things.

Like me again, this morning, after having answered the door. I returned to the conference room and everyone had split into groups. I sat at the edge of the group, trying to stay awake, still no coffee in hand. When we came back together with the other groups, I was appointed my group's reporter. I **babbled and rambled** about increasing staff capacity through subsidized coffee credits, and installing an electronic key system that would eliminate the need for staffers to have to manually open the front door to the office. As of this afternoon, I am seeking new employment.

Answer (score -1):

"Spazzing out" (which is a bit derogatory but not especially offensive) is more about being clumsy. "Spacing out" or "zoning out" cover the sleepy part of the question, but don't really address talking. "Brain fart" does a better job, but that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with dozing off. Really, I'm not too familiar with anyone speaking, sensibly or not, as they doze off. When someone talks in their sleep it is usually pretty silly, but that comes entirely from the unconscious mind. I'm not sure there is a word for this.

Comment: I assume *spazzed out* derives from the noun *[spaz](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spaz) = spastic*. Even if I'm mistaken, I still think it's a *lot* more offensive than, say, [niggardly](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Controversies_about_the_word_%22niggardly%22)

Comment: The offensiveness is subjective, but I think niggardly would be more offensive because it is basically a chosen behavior so the word would be commenting on character more than involuntary movement. Just my opinion, of course.

Comment: I suppose by some definitions, "offensiveness" is always subjective. But I imagine most UK parents would be absolutely delighted to hear their teenage offspring use such a recondite term as *niggardly*. Almost nobody in the UK perceives any link between that and *nigger* (unless they've heard of the occasional kerfuffle in the US, which just makes us roll our eyes). But [The Spastics Society](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spastic) changed its name a couple of decades ago because even that form is pretty bad. *Spaz* falls somewhere between *fuck* and *cunt* for most adult Brits.